# Zsh outputting extra newlines when echoing a multiline variable?

Tags: echo, zsh

It has something to do with having `promptsubst` set to on.  See below:

```
[/Users/darren]# var="Testing...
dquote>1,
dquote>2,
dquote>3,
dquote>Testing..."
[/Users/darren]# setopt promptsubst
[/Users/darren]# echo $var




Testing...
1,
2,
3,
Testing...
[/Users/darren]# echo "$var"




Testing...
1,
2,
3,
Testing...
[/Users/darren]# unsetopt promptsubst
[/Users/darren]# echo "$var"         
Testing...
1,
2,
3,
Testing...
[/Users/darren]# echo $var           
Testing...
1,
2,
3,
Testing...
[/Users/darren]#
```

In this case, I set my prompt to something very simple, so that I was sure it wasn't a goofed up prompt, but my real prompt requires `promptsubst` be on for showing Git status.  I've also noticed that it happens with something like `echo $var | grep Test`.  Any ideas how I can fix this while still keeping `promptsubst` on?

I'm running zsh 4.3.11 and using Oh-My-Zsh if that helps?

Thanks!

Comment: I was having the same error, Thanks, I`m not the only one :)

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. After testing it by disabling OMZ, I found out something in OMZ was the cause. I managed to narrow the issue down to the file `libs/termsupport.zsh`. It seems that there are issues with Terminal.app on Mac OS X and updating the tab titles.  I've posted a fix to Github: https://github.com/darrenclark/oh-my-zsh/commit/8f89d4d5a5d584bae288d8111d83a6489a1369dc